# What does it mean by "apex of the vortex of perpetual living"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I have read somewhere "apex of the vortex of perpetual living". What does it mean?

Comment: Have you looked up the words you don't know?

Comment: It isn't the nadir of the vortex of death. That's about all we can say.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Are you sure? I read somewhere that the vortex of perpetual living and the vortex of death are coincident but inversely oriented perspectives on the same swirling orb of eternal destiny, making the zenith (or "apex") of one the nadir of the other. Unless I misunderstood. Or the source was wrong. ;)

Comment: Seriously, could you tell where you read this or provide some of the surrounding context? It's a very strange phrase, possibly intended to be somewhat incomprehensible in order to achieve a poetic effect. Or, it could be the jargon of a religious cult. Or, it could be satire. An ordinary fluent speaker of English would have to know more about where it came from to make a confident guess about its meaning.

Comment: Or the *maelstrom* of death, if you imagine that vortices go *up*, and maelstroms go *down*.

Comment: @BenKovitz Without any context, I'd guess that the writer is throwing together all the obscure words he knows to make a pretentious, or at least mysterious-sounding, phrase. But who knows? It may come from a book where the idea is discussed in detail and by the time you get to that sentence it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Ben Kovitz:  Was it an interview with David Lynch by any chance? :)

Comment: One of my friends has kept this as his what's up status.

Comment: If you have any idea about more similar strong phrases like this..please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

At first glance, it looks rather like word salad, or some very flowery prose; still, we can try to parse it out.

**Apex** refers to the peak of something, the highest point, either literally - "the apex of a roof" meaning the highest point of the building - or figuratively.

**Vortex** refers to a swirling vertical structure, like a tornado, where a fluid spins around a central point, normally while moving down at the same time.

**Perpetual living** would literally mean living either forever, or without an obvious end in sight. A more metaphorical use, which seems appropriate in this context, might be the notion of living one's life to the fullest, filling every moment with experiences.

So, I would say that **vortex of perpetual living** might refer to a crazed, highly energetic lifestyle like that of a rock star or other celebrity determined to "live fast and die young" - a life always lived for excitement and excess. In which case the whole phrase would refer to the high point of this lifestyle, the moment when one is at one's peak, before the inevitable crash afterward.

BUT, without the context, I cannot say for sure that that's what is being referenced.

Comment: It gladdens my heart to see that an answer like this, to a question like this, can get (at least) 4 upvotes on ELL. It *is* instructive to see how fluent speakers make sense of unconventional expressions.

Comment: Dhanyawaad (It means Thanks in Hindi). Very helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without additional context. What are you reading? What are the sentences before and after this one?

The "vortex of perpetual living" seems to me some kind of metaphor or image that is likely set up elsewhere in the text. From just this sentence it brings to mind the idea of life as an eternal cycle, since a *vortex* is something swirling around, like a whirlpool or a tornado.

To be at its "apex" would mean to be at its peak or summit, which seems a little bit impossible if we're talking about an unending circle (which has no peak!). So the sentence may be deliberately nonsensical to make a point. Again, it depends on the context.